# Use Mapper.Initialize() for multiple mappings

Tags: asp.net, automapper

I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) V.6.1.1 as a mapper in my ASP.Net project. 
Before I had configuration as below:

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<A, B>();
            cfg.CreateMap<C, D>().ForMember(dest => dest.CityDesc, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.City));
        });
  var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
  var var1= mapper.Map<B>(request);
  var var2= mapper.Map<List<C>, List<D>>(result);
```

Now, I want to refactor the code, using `Mapper.Initialize()`. So I used:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<A, B>();
            cfg.CreateMap<C, D>().ForMember(dest => dest.CityDesc, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.City));
        });
  var var1= Mapper.Map<B>(request);
  var var2= Mapper.Map<List<C>, List<D>>(result);
```

I have an run time error:

```
 Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types:    A-> B
```

Is there any problem with using multiple configurations in `Mapper.Initialize`? There is no error in the case that has one mapping in `Initialize()` body. How should I fix the error?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have more than one `Mapper.Initialize` in your project while **you should not have multiple `Mapper.Initialize` in your project** else it will become override and you lost previous mapping configurations that you set by `Mapper.Initialize`. Now It is possible to get the error (`Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.`)

---

I recommend you to use `AutoMapper.Profile`. You can warp your mapping configurations in the form of grouped (in separated Profiles) then register all of theme by `Mapper.Initialize` at once ;)

Look at this example:

```
public class AB_Profile : Profile {
    protected override void Configure() {
        CreateMap<A, B>();
     // CreateMap<A, B1>();
     // CreateMap<A, B2>();
    }
}

public class CD_Profile : Profile {
    protected override void Configure() {
        CreateMap<C, D>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CityDesc, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.City));
    }
}
```

Then initialize the Mapper using above Profiles:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<AB_Profile >();
    cfg.AddProfile<CD_Profile >();
});
```

Comment: @Elnaz, did my answer helped you to solve your problem? If that was the case, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Starting version 5 use this, as mentioned on their website...

```
public class OrganizationProfile : Profile
{
    public OrganizationProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
        // Use CreateMap... Etc.. here (Profile methods are the same as configuration methods)
    }
}

// How it was done in 4.x - as of 5.0 this is obsolete:
// public class OrganizationProfile : Profile
// {
//     protected override void Configure()
//     {
//         CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
//     }
// }
```

[See Doc](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html)

Then initialize the mapping as...

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
    cfg.AddProfile<OrganizationProfile>();
});
```